# How to onclick one element and add text in another element

Tags: javascript, onclick, innerhtml

I swear I've tried to find this question answered all over this forum and google in general and haven't found a solution.  Probably because I'm completely wrong.

I am trying to code in pure javascript, and I want the user to click on a picture, then the count increment shows up to the right of the picture.

In my counter(getpic) function I get an error message that " document.getElementById(cat).innerHTML = count;" is Null.  I've checked and double checked and nothing is null.  I feel like it has something to do with the fact the onclick is attached to the pic and can't communicate with the paragraph element, but I'm a newb and haven't even been able to find a workaround in pure javascript if this is the case.

html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>

<title>Cat Click</title>


</head>


<body>

<div id="container" style="white-space:nowrap">
        <div style="display:inline;">
            <div onClick="counter(this.id)" id="Cat pic 1">
            <img src="http://example.com/pic1.png"  height="400" width="400">
            <p id="Cat id 1" style="display:inline; white-space:nowrap;"></p>
            </div>
        </div>
</div>


<div id="container" style="white-space:nowrap">
        <div style="display:inline;">
            <div onClick="counter(this.id)" id="Cat pic 2">
            <img src="http://example.com/pic2.png"  height="400" width="400" >
            <p id="Cat id 2" style="display:inline; white-space:nowrap;"></p>
            </div>
        </div>
</div>

<div id="container" style="white-space:nowrap">
        <div style="display:inline;">
            <div onClick="counter(this.id)" id="Cat pic 3">
            <img src="http://example.com/pic3.png"  height="400" width="400" >
            <p id="Cat id 3" style="display:inline; white-space:nowrap;"></p>
             </div>
        </div>
</div>

<div id="container" style="white-space:nowrap">
        <div style="display:inline;">
            <div onClick="counter(this.id)" id="Cat pic 4">
            <img src="http://example.com/pic4.png"  height="400" width="400" >
            <p id="Cat id 4" style="display:inline; white-space:nowrap;"></p>
            </div>
        </div>
</div>


<div id="container" style="white-space:nowrap">        
        <div style="display:inline;">
            <div onClick="counter(this.id)" id="Cat pic 5" >
            <img src="http://example.com/pic5.png"  height="400" width="400" >
            <p id="Cat id 5" style="display:inline; white-space:nowrap;"></p>
            </div>
        </div>
</div>

<script src="catclick.js"></script>





</body>


</html>
```

Javascript

```
var count1 = 0;
var count2 = 0;
var count3 = 0;
var count4 = 0;
var count5 = 0;

idCats = ["Cat id 1", "Cat id 2", "Cat id 3","Cat id 4","Cat id 5"]
picCats = [null, "Cat pic 1", "Cat pic 2", "Cat pic 3","Cat pic 4","Cat pic 5"] 
idCount = [null, count1, count2, count3, count4, count5]



function counter(getpic) {
    for (var i = 1; i < 6; i++) {

            if (getpic===picCats[i]) {
                var countIndex = idCount[i];
                console.log(countIndex);
                countIndex++
                count = countIndex;
                console.log(count);
                var catid = "Cat id " + i;  
                console.log(catid);
                var cat = document.getElementById(catid);
                console.log(count);
                console.log(cat);
                debugger
                document.getElementById(cat).innerHTML = count;
            } 

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your example code, the variable `cat` is an actual DOM element you retrieved 4 lines above:

```
var cat = document.getElementById(catid);
```

The line in question should read:

```
cat.innerHTML = count;
```

Answer (score 0):

You are writing it this way:

```
var cat = document.getElementById(catid);
...
document.getElementById(cat).innerHTML = count;
```

which translates to:

```
var cat = document.getElementById(catid);
...
document.getElementById(document.getElementById(catid)).innerHTML = count;
```

The correct way is:

```
var cat = document.getElementById(catid);
...
cat.innerHTML = count;
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you guys!  I realize now that I was trying to pull from the DOM element twice.

Also, I realized my count was resetting because I didn't use something like splice to update my count array.

It works now!

Thanks again.